# Como comparar duas datas iguais com horas diferentes para saber qual é a maior? Utilizando PHP

Tags: php

Fiz isso aqui, mas o código compara apenas a parte da data, se tiver duas datas iguais com horas diferentes, ele diz que é igual, mas quero comparar qual é a maior também pela hora. (ignorem a primeira parte de separação e concatenação de string porque é devido ao formato de dado que vou receber futuramente)

```
<?php    
  $data_hora1 = '12-30-2022_15:24';
  $hora1 = substr($data_hora1, -5); 
  $dia1 = substr($data_hora1, 3, 3);
  $mes1 = substr($data_hora1, 0, 3);
  $ano1 = substr($data_hora1, 6, 4);
  $data1=$dia1.$mes1.$ano1;    
  $dh1=$data1." ".$hora1.":00";
  echo "d-m-a H-m-s (1) ".$dh1."<br>";
  $data_hora2 = '12-30-2022_18:24';
  $hora2 = substr($data_hora2, -5); 
  $dia2 = substr($data_hora2, 3, 3);
  $mes2 = substr($data_hora2, 0, 3);
  $ano2 = substr($data_hora2, 6, 4);    
  $data2=$dia2.$mes2.$ano2;
  $dh2=$data2." ".$hora2.":00";
  echo "d-m-a H-m-s (1) ". $dh2."<br>";

if(strtotime($dh1) > strtotime($dh2))
{
    echo 'A data 1 é maior que a data 2.';
}
elseif(strtotime($data1) == strtotime($data2))
{
    echo 'A data 1 é igual a data 2.';
}
else
{
    echo 'A data 1 é menor a data 2.';
}
?>
```

Comment: não, o problema não era esse, porque estava funcionando, só que comparando apenas a data e nao as horas. Consegui resolver utilizando a função getTimestamp() que pega a data e a hora completa

Answer (score -3):

Conseguir resolver assim (caso alguem tenha a mesma duvida no futuro):

```
<?php    
    $data_hora1 = '12-30-2022_15:25';
  $hora1 = substr($data_hora1, -5); 
  $dia1 = substr($data_hora1, 3, 3);
  $mes1 = substr($data_hora1, 0, 3);
  $ano1 = substr($data_hora1, 6, 4);



$data1=$dia1.$mes1.$ano1;


  $dh1=$data1." ".$hora1.":00";
    echo "d-m-a H-m-s (1) ".$dh1."<br>";



    $data_hora2 = '12-30-2022_15:25';
  $hora2 = substr($data_hora2, -5); 
  $dia2 = substr($data_hora2, 3, 3);
  $mes2 = substr($data_hora2, 0, 3);
  $ano2 = substr($data_hora2, 6, 4);

$data2=$dia2.$mes2.$ano2;


  $dh2=$data2." ".$hora2.":00";
    echo "d-m-a H-m-s (2) ". $dh2."<br>";

    $entrada = new DateTime($dh1);
    $saida = new DateTime($dh2);


if($entrada->getTimestamp() > $saida->getTimestamp())
{
echo 'A data 1 é maior que a data 2.';
}
elseif($entrada->getTimestamp() == $saida->getTimestamp())
{
echo 'A data 1 é igual a data 2.';
}
else
{
echo 'A data 1 é menor a data 2.';
}


?>
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português. Esse código pode ser uma solução para a pergunta, mas sua resposta pode ser melhor se você [edit] e incluir uma explicação sobre os principais pontos do código. O objetivo não é ajudar apenas quem fez a pergunta, mas os próximos visitantes também. Leia mais em [Respostas apenas com código - O que fazer?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7172/).

Answer (score -3):

Para comparar duas datas com horas diferentes no PHP, você pode criar objetos DateTime para cada uma das datas e depois compará-las usando a função.

Antes de comparar as datas precisamos converter elas para formato americano

```
<?php

function converterDataParaPadraoAmericano(string $data)
{
    // Cria um objeto DateTime com o formato de entrada especificado
    $datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y_H:i', $data);

    // Formata a data no formato desejado (padrão americano)
    $data_formatada = $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    return  $data_formatada; // Saída: 2022-12-30 15:24:00
}


$data_hora1 = converterDataParaPadraoAmericano('12-30-2022_15:24');
$data_hora2 = converterDataParaPadraoAmericano('12-30-2022_18:24');
```

Você pode criar objetos DateTime para cada uma delas usando a classe DateTime do PHP da seguinte maneira:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime($data_hora1);
$datetime2 = new DateTime($data_hora2);
```

Agora, para comparar as duas datas e determinar qual é a maior, você pode usar o operador > ou < para comparar os objetos DateTime

```
if ($datetime1 > $datetime2) {
    echo "A primeira data é maior";
} elseif ($datetime1 < $datetime2) {
    echo "A segunda data é maior";
} else {
    echo "As datas são iguais";
}
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português. Esse código pode ser uma solução para a pergunta, mas sua resposta pode ser melhor se você [edit] e incluir uma explicação sobre os principais pontos do código. O objetivo não é ajudar apenas quem fez a pergunta, mas os próximos visitantes também. Leia mais em [Respostas apenas com código - O que fazer?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7172/).

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda!

Comment: Olá @stefani, fico feliz em ter ajudado! No entanto, observei que minha resposta ainda não foi marcada como a correta. Você poderia, por favor, considerar marcar minha resposta como a correta para ajudar outros usuários que possam ter o mesmo problema? Agradeço antecipadamente pela sua consideração